# android single item context menu

Tags: android, contextmenu, onlongclicklistener

I have an onLongClickListener set up for a layout. On long click I need a context menu with singe "Delete" option. What is the most simple way to manage that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ....

    mView = someView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Menu Title");
    MenuItem remove = menu.add("Delete");

    remove.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            //doStuff...
        }
    });

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

and in onLongPress or something you can call [openContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openContextMenu%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, it's pretty simple and works nicely